# slick lift embed sql 'OR' equivalent

Tags: scala, slick

```
   val Users = TableQuery[User] 
   Users.filter(_.age === 18 or _.age is null)
```

How to achieve above query with slick?

The sql expected

```
select * from user where age = 18 or age is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick uses Scala syntax where ever possible. Use `||` instead of `or`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on the filter based query, but a For Comprehension will get you exactly what you're looking for:

```
val forCol = for {
  u <- Users if u.username === "Damiya" || u.username === "OtherDamiya"
} yield u
```

Will generate the following query, assuming a standard table definition of Users

```
select x2."id", x2."username", x2."first_name", x2."last_name", x2."email",  x2."password" 
from "users" x2 
where (x2."username" = 'Damiya') or (x2."username" = 'OtherDamiya')
```

I've found that for-comprehensions are the easiest way to work with slick because you can easily leverage joins and so on.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
 val Users = TableQuery[User] 
 Users.filter(m => ((m.age is 18) || (m.age isNull)))
```